# Pass pointer of object/etc. to a slot

Tags: c++, qt

Actually I can do it this way:
In mainfen.h:

```
private:
QPushButton *m_edit; //declare the button
```

In mainfen.cpp:

```
mainFen::mainFen()
{
    [...]
    m_edit = new QPushButton; //create a new button
    m_edit->setCheckable(true); //set a property of it
    [...]
}
void mainFen::onSomethingClicked() // is a slot
{
    [...]
    m_edit->setChecked(true); //we want to set a property of the button
    [...]
}
```

But I don't think it's the right way to do that, I think that I have to do like that:
mainfen.h is without the *m_edit definition and mainfen.cpp is:

```
mainFen::mainFen()
{
    [...]
    QPushButton *edit = new QPushButton; //create a new button
    edit->setCheckable(true); //set a property of it
    [...]
}
void mainFen::onSomethingClicked() // is a slot
{
    [...]
    edit->setChecked(true); //we want to set a property of the button
    [...]
}
```

But this will not work because edit is not part of onSomethingClicked() slot, how can I make it work? Thank in advance.

Comment: Why do you think that first way is not the way to do it? Does it not compile? Does it not work?

Comment: It does compile and works fine, but I don't think that's the right way to do it because I've seen some code with things like ui->boutonEdit->setChecked(false); to modify object out of the function (or constructor) where they were declared.

Comment: Well, you *can't* do it like the second example, but another way of doing it would be to put the new push button object into some container or other class where it could be looked up or referenced later (but this is not necessarily much different from the first example).

Comment: Ok, then I will continue to use the first method :)